# Location of HTTP log format for Haproxy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, haproxy

with this example in my configuration

```
    frontend http-in
        mode http
        option httplog
        log global
        default_backend bck

    backend static
        server srv1 127.0.0.1:8000
```

where can i view the logs for my load balancer? (Haproxy)

Answer (score 1):

following this guide solved my problem

[Haproxy Logging in Ubuntu](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/haproxy_logging/)

created a script that is located in /var/logs/